# SQL Server: Compare current row with all previous rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the following data, sorted by Name and Date

```
Row Name   Pos  Date
--- ----   ---- ----
1   Anne    A   11/01/2014
2   Anne    A   11/02/2014
3   Anne    C   11/04/2014
4   Anne    B   11/06/2014
5   Anne    C   11/08/2014
6   Jane    A   11/01/2014
7   Jane    A   11/02/2014
8   Jane    C   11/03/2014
9   Mark    B   11/01/2014
10  Mark    A   11/04/2014
11  Mark    A   11/06/2014
12  Mark    B   11/07/2014
13  Mark    C   11/08/2014
```

The rule is that a user should not be at `C` before at least he/she has been at `A` twice. Once the user is in `C` he/she must be in `A` twice or more again before he/she is in `C`.  How do you find which users have followed this rule?

For this example the answer should be `Jane` and `Mark`.  `Anne` violates the rule at row 5.

Comment: You have to be clearer with your rules: at row 5 `Anne` **has** been at `A` twice. Do you mean "must have been at `A` twice since the last time they were at `C`?

Comment: @Isaac: I made the rule more clearer.

Comment: what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @w0lf: SQL Server 2012

Comment: Just to make it explicit: you're trying to implement state machines in SQL. This article might be helpful: https://ef.gy/fsm-recursive-sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your table is called `Records`, here's how you could do it leveraging SQL Server 2012's [LAG window function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx):

First, let's find the users who break the rule:

```
;with ACRecords as (
  select Row, Name, Date, Pos
  from Records
  where Pos in ('A', 'C')
),
AC3ConsecutiveRecords as (
    select
    Name,
    Pos,
    lag(Pos, 1) over (partition by Name order by Date) as LastPos,
    lag(Pos, 2) over (partition by Name order by Date) as SecondToLastPos
    from ACRecords
)
select 
    Name
from AC3ConsecutiveRecords
where Pos = 'C' and (LastPos <> 'A' or SecondToLastPos <> 'A')
```

This query does the following:

1. filter out records that have `Pos` values other than A or C.
2. from the data set obtained at point 1, select for each record the `Pos`, the `LastPos` and the `SecondToLastPos`, which we get using `LAG` (with appropriate `PARTITION` and `ORDER BY` clauses).
3. from the data set obtained at point 2, select the rows that have the `Pos` equal to C and former two `Pos` values different than A (at least one of them). Select the Name for each of these records. These are the people who broke the rule.

To get the people who obeyed the rule, simply wrap the last step in yet another CTE and select all people except the ones who broke the rule:

```
;with ACRecords as (
  select Row, Name, Date, Pos
  from Records
  where Pos in ('A', 'C')
),
AC3ConsecutiveRecords as (
    select
    Name,
    Pos,
    lag(Pos, 1) over (partition by Name order by Date) as LastPos,
    lag(Pos, 2) over (partition by Name order by Date) as SecondToLastPos
    from ACRecords
),
PeopleWhoBrokeTheRule as (
    select 
    distinct Name
    from AC3ConsecutiveRecords
    where Pos = 'C' and (LastPos <> 'A' or SecondToLastPos <> 'A')
)
select 
    distinct Name
from Records
except (select Name from PeopleWhoBrokeTheRule);
```

#### EDIT:

SQLFiddle's SQL 2012 instance is currently down, but fortunately the query works fine in Postgres, so here is a live version: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bed67/1

Answer (score 0):

Let's setup the scene:

```
declare @table table(row int,name varchar(9),pos char(1),date smalldatetime)
insert @table values(1,'Anne','A','20141101')
insert @table values(2,'Anne','A','20141102')
insert @table values(3,'Anne','C','20141104')
insert @table values(4,'Anne','B','20141106')
insert @table values(5,'Anne','C','20141108')
insert @table values(6,'Jane','A','20141101')
insert @table values(7,'Jane','A','20141102')
insert @table values(8,'Jane','C','20141103')
insert @table values(9,'Mark','B','20141101')
insert @table values(10,'Mark','A','20141104')
insert @table values(11,'Mark','A','20141106')
insert @table values(12,'Mark','B','20141107')
insert @table values(13,'Mark','C','20141108')
```

The query below gives the expected results:

```
select distinct a.name 
from @table a 
where a.pos = 'C'
-- 1. ensure that there are no C's which is followed by less than 2 A's
and not exists (
    select * from @table b where a.name = b.name and b.pos = 'C' and b.date < a.date
    and (select count(*) from @table c where a.name = c.name and c.pos = 'A' and c.date < a.date and c.date > b.date) < 2) 
-- 2. ensure that there are no C pairs which have less than 2 A's between them
and not exists (
    select * from @table d join @table e on d.name = e.name
    where d.pos = 'C' and e.pos = 'C' and d.name = a.name and d.date < e.date
    and (select count(*) from @table f where f.name = a.name and f.pos = 'A' and f.date < e.date and f.date > d.date) < 2)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the only solution would be to create a trigger instead of insert which checks this

(select count(pos) from inserted where pos = C) <= (select  2 * count(pos) from inserted where pos = A)

and rollsback or commits depending on the outcome